# Opengl calculate triangle derivatives

Tags: opengl, math, derivative

I have a triangle in 2D space.
I have  screen space coordinates of each vertex, and I have attribute values of each vertex.

How can I calculate dFdx / dFdy for those attributes? In other words, how will change attribute from screen pixel to pixel.

```
//fragment shader
varrying vec2 myAttr;

void main(void)
{
  vec2 px = dFdx(myAttr);
  vec2 py = dFdy(myAttr);
}
```

I want to get px, py. I need to know delta(grow) of `myAttr` from next pixel for x and y axis. 
I need formula /algorithm how to calculate them manually (for example for cases when hardware does not support derivatives).

P.S. Attribute value linear interpolated between 3 vertices (according to OpenGL doc).

Comment: I don't get what you're asking. You already have the GLSL builtin functions dFdx, dFdy in your code. What more do you want? An explanation of how to calculate it manually?

Comment: This is in GLSL :) I need formula to calculate them manually/on CPU.

Comment: This thread on the opengl forums asks a very similar question: http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/176425-How-are-dFdx-and-dFdy-functions-implemented.

Comment: derivative means rate of change per unit. Your unit in here is distance between pixels. Change is the difference of function value at adjacent points. So this must be just a simple approximated division with one of higher order formulas like a "5 point stencil" but on three points instead.

Comment: @huseyin tugrul buyukisik - Well yes. And I understand how to do linear interpolation between 2 points. But I can't figure out, how to interpolate between 3.

Comment: It was something derived from Taylor series or some Euler equations. Let me search more if someone else not searching already. Here: http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/numericaldiffmod.html

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik "It was something derived from Taylor series or some Euler equations." - You mean interpolation between 3 points, or derivation?

Comment: Ive meant Derivation. Interpolation has linear and exponential versions hasnt it?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I know only this one `current = (max-min)*pos`, where pos = 0..1 :) And I know that this is linear interpolation. How to interpolate between 3 values I have no idea. And it would be good if someone show how interpolation calculated particularly in OpenGL/DirectX/whatever hardware (GL_LINEAR).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming your vertex are structured like this:

```
struct vertex
{
  double x; // screenspace x coordinate
  double y; // screenspace y coordinate
  double a; // your attribute
};
```

The derivation you're looking for are calculated like this:

```
      d    = (v0.x - v2.x) * (v1.y - v2.y) -
             (v1.x - v2.x) * (v0.y - v2.y);

      dfdx = ((v0.a - v2.a) * (v1.y - v2.y) -
              (v1.a - v2.a) * (v0.y - v2.y)) / d;

      dfdy = ((v0.a - v2.a) * (v1.x - v2.x) -
              (v1.a - v2.a) * (v0.x - v2.x)) / d;
```

Note that this equation becomes unstable as `d` approaches zero. It will also cause a divide by zero if `d` is exactly zero. This is not a problem in practice because in this case the triangle also has a area of zero and nothing needs to be rendered.

Comment: Wow. Exactly what I need. You found those equations by yourself, or this is some known way to get them? I mean, if this is some known thing, can I read about this somewhere?

Comment: And, it seems that attribute can be vector in your equations. Am I right? Or better calculate it per component?

Comment: @tower120 d is just a common factor that I pulled out of the equation to make them simpler. If I remember right it is twice the area of the triangle. Yes, you can replace the scalar a with a vector of attributes. That will work just as well. I don't know where I got the equations from but I didn't come up with them by myself. As far as I remember they are derived by starting with barycentric coordinates, then solving for a single interpolated value and simplifying the equations.

Comment: I cut and pasted the equations more or less directly from a old triangle rasterizer code that I've written back in the 90th. :-)

Comment: in `dfdx` you operate with `y` component. Is this correct?

Comment: yep. It is correct. Since we divide the entire equation by d the y component cancels out and the x component remains in the equation.

Comment: My dFdy seems always inverted by sign http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=90985762636944752928 (mathematica file), or simple txt http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=57702494364821549967

Comment: Must be we use different indices order. What was in your rasterizer? Counterclockwise?